# Field name with a leading underscore in Model

Tags: python, django-models

Given a following model:

```
from django.db import models
class A(models.Model):
    _number = models.IntegerField()
```

Is it all right to have a leading underscore in a field name?
What about use in Querysets?

Specifically I am concerned about the situation when there is another model B:

```
class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

Then what would be the naming rule for queries?

```
B.objects.filter(a___number__in=(1,2,3)) or
B.objects.filter(a__number__in=(1,2,3))
```

Comment: Is it `models.Model`? -- Also, FwIW, I'm assuming that the metaclass is [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L60) and I don't see anything to make me believe that an underscore prefix wouldn't work (but I did only look at it for about 1 min ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's ok.
Yes, in QuerySets you should use them with leading underscore:

```
A.objects.filter(_number__in=(1,2,3)).count()
```

Comment: And if it appears in a foreign key relationship? So there would be another model B having a ForeignKeyField 'a' to A. Then what the query looks like? B.objects.filter(a__number_in=(1,2,3)).count() or B.objects.filter(a___number_in=(1,2,3)).count()?

Comment: @kitek, sorry, didn't see your edit. I think, that this will not work, but this is bad idea even if this works. When you read code rapidly, you are not counting extra underscores, so many errors like you `a__number__in` or (as you did) `a___number_in` are possible.. the second one is easy to see. The first one is tricky

Comment: So finally it's not really ok to use it?

Comment: @kitek No, you could use them, but with some limitations.

Comment: Thank you. Although I'm expecting to use this field in many ways so I will restrain myself from adding '_'.